# Changes to model behavior when converting between Gazebo 1.0 and Gazebo 1.8

Tags: gazebo-1.8

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi All,

I've been modelling an arm which uses a plugin that models hydraulic actuators and valves. The model is a state representation that uses actuator velocity and acceleration as states and outputs force.

to link to gazebo model I get my velocity state from the joints using joint::GetVelocity() in the model and apply my actuator force to the joints via joint::SetForce().

These are both done on the plugin's OnUpdate()

This works fine with Gazebo 1.0 and the model was controllable.

I recently converted over standalone Gazebo 1.7, and the joint response was no longer sufficient to defeat gravity and my actuators that previously responded correctly now can no longer lift the links of my manipulator.

My gravity vector is (0, 0, -9.8)

Additionally my model's joints jerk around quite a bit without input from any controller to the plugin.

I'm just wondering if there have been any changes that may be causing this behavior in the new Gazebo. I haven't significantly modified my models or plugins other than to convert them for Gazebo 1.7. As a result the plugin did have to be outside ROS as per the Tutorials1.5/ros_plugin. but was functionally unchanged.

Any suggestions as to what may be wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3237/changes-to-model-behavior-when-converting-between-gazebo-1.0-and-gazebo-1.8/) by [PMilani](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/92/pmilani/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 203 on 2013-06-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Quick answer. My actuator models have always been [stiff](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/553/effect-of-stiffness-and-mass-on-gazebo-simulation/).

I still needed to change the solver parameters for dt and iters as the default values were not small enough and had to be changed to dt = 0.0001 and iters=100. The sim_time/realtime ratio was 0.1. Changed the <update_rate> to 10000 and it pushed the ratio up to 0.75 where it seems to be holding.

---

Originally posted by [PMilani](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/92/pmilani/) with karma: 203 on 2013-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0